# Windows program that will trim M4A/AAC files without any loss

Tags: windows, audio, media-converter, audio-editing

I have some M4A audio files (with an AAC codec) that I need to perform basic trimming operations on. The problem is that, to my understanding, the few programs that support M4A/AAC files trim the files lossily. Some research came up with a few programs that do so without loss, without re-encoding the file, namely Fission and Boilersoft Video Splitter; the former is OSX-only, and the latter is paid. Does anyone know of any freeware programs that will do what I want?

**Requirements**

- Needs to be free
- Needs to work through a GUI
- Needs to run on Windows 7
- Needs to be able to trim M4A/AAC files without re-encoding them

Would really appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) + a GUI such as [Avanti](http://avanti.arrozcru.org). FFMPEG allows all sorts of operations on the majority of video & **audio** files including trimming without recoding from the command line and Avanti provides a GUI that boasts access to all of the FFMPEG features.

To trim an Audio file from the command line without re-encoding and skipping the first minute then limiting the time to 10 minutes you would use:

```
ffmpeg -i Infile.ext -acodec copy -ss 00:01:00.000 -t 00:00:10.000 Outfile.ext
```

***N.B.*** *the .ext* ***must*** *be the same for both the input and output file if you wish to avoid re-encoding the file.*

Any decent FFMPEG GUI should let you do the same

Screenshot from the Avanti web site:
[image]

Comment: The only thing I would add to your answer is that the outfile.ext is very important - if you add outfile.mp4 it'll try to create a "standards compliant" MP4 file - if your input and conversion options don't match that you'll probably get an error.

Comment: Thanks for this, Steve. I'm no stranger to the command line, but for ease of use, I decided to give Avanti a try. One thing I'm confused about is where it specifies the bitrate - isn't it the case that there's no point in recoding an audio file to a higher bitrate because there's no sound quality to be gained? I just wanted to confirm that.

Comment: @Hashim Once something has been encoded at a given bit rate re-encoding at a higher bit rate will not improve the sound quality as the data just isn't there. _You might still do it if the destination device struggles with the lower rate._ Leaving the destination Audio settings un-ticked should be the same as `-acodec copy` to not re-encode the audio or not changing the settings that it is populated with once the input file is selected will.